# Can I add a user to a SharePoint Group in a workflow

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, permissions

We need to have a list where contributors request new users to be added to a site. The site owner then needs to approve this request on the list (the users wnat to see the progress of their request as well as additional info about the users contained in the list. Once (if) approved the new user needs to be added to the specific group as requested.

I'd really prefer to avoid the Site Owner having to BOTH approve the list item AND still have to go and add the new user to the relevant SharePoint Group (eg viewer/contributor/etc) - can this be done in SPD 2010 (we are running SharePoint 2010 Enterprise licence)?

Answer (score 4):

Not that I'm aware of.  Third party workflow tools like Nintex workflow allow you to call Sharepoint web services, so in these instances I've been able to add users to groups in workflow.

To do the same in SPD, you'd need to develop your own workflow actions to do that(or get a third party workflow tool like Nintex Workflow or K2), then use impersenation steps to add the user to a group.

Answer (score 2):

http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/releases/view/89201

The Solutions includes the following SharePoint Designer Workflow Actions:

- Create Site Action
- Create Group Action
- Add Users to Group Action

Comment: worked like a charm, but you have to use in Impersonation step.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is no out of the box action to do this, but there is a custom free solution that does exactly this: http://natalyavoskresenskay.codeplex.com/