# Add/Remove users from permissions group via workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, permissions

I know how to grant permissions to groups via workflow, but is there a way to add and remove people from those permissions groups via workflow?  For example, if the user entered the users who should be in the group via peoplepicker, then the workflow would place those users into the appropriate permissions group.  Is this a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the custom workflow action solution from this link. However, if you have third-party workflow tool like Nintex, you can easily find this action.

http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/releases/view/89201

The Solutions includes the following SharePoint Designer Workflow Actions:

- Create Site Action
- Create Group Action
- Add Users to Group Action

Similar question is discussed here :

[Can I add a user to a SharePoint Group in a workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12468/can-i-add-a-user-to-a-sharepoint-group-in-a-workflow)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot change or install DLL's, etc.  That's all I'm finding from the link.  I'm stuck using the SharePoint tools at hand, including JS Script Editors. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you configured **Workflow Manager** for your farm, you can use "Call HTTP web service" action to call users REST API, then add/remove a user from a group.

[Users REST API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn531432%28v%3Doffice.15%29)

[Workflow – Useful REST calls – Add user to group](http://codelesssharepointinfopath.com/workflow-useful-rest-calls-add-user-to-group/)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have that sort of access.